# What SQL indexes to put for big table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have two big tables from which I mostly select but complex queries with 2 joins are extremely slow.

First table is GameHistory in which I store records for every finished game (I have 15 games in separate table).
Fields: id, date_end, game_id, ..

Second table is GameHistoryParticipants in which I store records for every player participated in certain game.
Fields: player_id, history_id, is_winner

Query to get top players today is very slow (20+ seconds).
Query:

```
SELECT p.nickname, count(ghp.player_id) as num_games_today  
FROM `GameHistory` as gh 
INNER JOIN GameHistoryParticipants as ghp ON gh.id=ghp.history_id    

INNER JOIN Players as p ON p.id=ghp.player_id     

WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, gh.date_end, NOW())=0 AND gh.game_id='scrabble' 

GROUP BY ghp.player_id ORDER BY count(ghp.player_id) DESC LIMIT 10
```

First table has 1.5 million records and the second one 3.5 million. 
What indexes should I put ? (I tried some and it was all slow)

Comment: *Very slow* - how slow are we talking? How are you measuring speed?

Comment: 27 seconds. I'm running the query in phpMyAdmin and it tells me

Comment: have a read of:http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/142644-create-index-large-table

Comment: @Deyan Vitanov I find this slideshow about indexes a really big help. Read [here](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)

Answer (score 1):

You are only interested in today's records. However, you search the whole GameHistory table with TIMESTAMPDIFF to detect those records. Even if you have an index on that column, it cannot be used, due to the fact that you use a function on the field.

You should have an index on both fields game_id and date_end. Then ask for the date_end value directly:

```
WHERE gh.date_end >= DATE(NOW())
AND gh.date_end < DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND gh.game_id = 'scrabble'
```

It would even be better to have an index on date_end's *date part* rather then on the whole time carrying date_end. This is not possible in MySQL however. So consider adding another column trunc_date_end for the date part alone which you'd fill with a before-insert trigger. Then you'd have an index on trunc_date_end and game_id, which should help you find the desired records in no time.

```
WHERE gh.trunc_date_end = DATE(NOW())
AND gh.game_id = 'scrabble'
```

Comment: Very useful - thanks I'll try, but I have similar queries to get not only today's top players, but weekly top and monthly top.
Strange is that after adding game_id & date_end indexes it did not get much faster, but when I removed join to Players table - it become fast (1sec)

Comment: That certainly is strange, because there must be a foreign key in ghp on the players table, right? So getting the Player records should be extremely fast. (BTW: If table Players has many columns, you can always use the trick to build an index on id + nickname, so it suffices to read the index alone without having to access the table.)

Comment: As to weekly and monthly top: That shouldn't matter. You are only interested in part of the table's data, so being able to use an index with direct column access (`gh.date_end >= ...` , `gh.date_end <= ...` or even `gh.trunc_date_end = ...`) should speed things up.

Comment: I have primary key index on Players table (on id field). And yes - there are many fields there (26). I also added the nickname to primary index but it is still slow. Players table has 180k records

Comment: No, what I am talking about that you should have an index on ghp.player_id (which would only be natural as this is your foreign key to table Players). Also: Primary key of table Players is of course the id. You can *add another* index containing both key and name, but don't change the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

add 'EXPLAIN' command at the beginning of your query then run it in a database viewer(ex: sqlyog) and you will see the details about the query, look for the 'rows' column and you will see different integer values. Now, index the table columns indicated in the EXPLAIN command result that contain large rows.

-i think my explanation is kinda messy, you can ask for clarification